# In need of some advice controlling a C# winforms application via a asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube, remote-server

I'm working on a little project for a basic Youtube remote control, whereby I have a helper app running on my PC, and then can send commands from a website accessed via the web browser on my phone.

Reading through threads on other sites from people trying to do the same thing I've realized it is not a concept that most people would be comfortable with, but I am struggling to think of another way to do it beyond writing a native app for my phone and having it communicate with the helper application internally via WLAN(Would be happy to do this, but don't have the cash to spring for a new mac to develop for my iphone).

If I were to stick with the Website/Winforms model, is there a way to do this in such a way that (most) people would be comfortable running?

The ideas I had so far were:

a) Build a web server into the helper app(Though not sure of the logistics of having it host an ASP.net site)

b) Host the site externally, and have the helper app periodically poll a database/webservice on a server to receive commands (Sketchy and i imagine very resource heavy)

Sorry for the wall of text, I'm capable of running with an idea and building it, I'm just not sure what is possible and considered the 'best' way to do something like this.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Cheers

**Edit** Thanks, just to be clear, when i say uncomfortable, I mean - Would you be ok with having a website being able to send potentially ANY command to your computer? This seems to be the problem raised in other discussions about this topic. Obviously I'm not trying to do anything malicious, but as I said, it seemed to be a concern.

Comment: You're a little unclear about why people are uncomfortable, and if you want answers related to comfort level, you need to be clearer about this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Robert, I hope I have clarified enough in the edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a controlled environment where you can always open a port on the firewall for incoming communication, you can have the web app make a WCF call back to the Windows Client through the users firewall.

If not (which is what I suspect), you may be better off polling a web service.  Just do it every few seconds and whatever you're checking in that web service call (a database?) make sure it's well optimized.  Perhaps just have it return some status int/enum or something very light weight to instruct the client on the next call to make (0 = no update, 1 = command1, 2 = command2, etc).

As for how you do the polling, you could do something like:

```
int seconds = 4;
System.Timers.Timer _clientTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(seconds * 1000);
_clientTimer.AutoReset = false;
_clientTimer.Elapsed += clientTimer_Elapsed;
_clientTimer.Start();

private void clientTimer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        // Connect to web service, get status, if status != 0 do something...
    }
    finally
    {
        _clientTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

NOTE: the auto-reset = false means that each time the Elapsed event fires, the timer is stopped.  In the approach I've taken, I let the timer stop so the client can process the web service results and then start the timer once again after it's done.  This will help prevent multiple requests from piling up if a connection is real slow.

That's all I can think of :)

Comment: Thanks Adam! The status calls are a great idea, I think if i went down the polling route that would definitely be the way to do it.

Comment: I'm looking more into the WCF idea, I'm happy with it being a controlled environment, i'd rather keep it internal over a network rather than polling out to a server I'm hosting if i can. I don't know a great deal about what is possible with WCF though. Could my 'helper' winforms app run the service and then have the website make calls to it? I suppose for it to be internal that would need the website hosted by the application as well though which brings me back to plan A...

Comment: There's definitely pros and cons to both approaches.  By doing the WCF thing you'll need to open up ports on the router and on any software firewalls running on the client's machine, but it will use less resources/traffic than the polling approach.  At my work we have a similar need for a web page to communicate with a winforms app.  We actually moved away from the WCF approach (actually it's predecessor: .NET Remoting) to the polling approach just because it required too much client configuration.  It really depends on your situation, though.

Comment: Thanks for your help Adam. With regards to the polling approach, the only thing i can think of is using a timer control. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I updated my answer with some sample code.  I wouldn't use the WinForms Timer control because I don't think it has that AutoReset property (I could be wrong?).  I typically use the `System.Timers.Timer` class, but it's really just a matter of preference I think.

Comment: Thanks alot Adam, I don't have the rep to upvote you, but I've marked it as the answer, you've been a big help!